# Mypy complains with "Class pattern class must not be a type alias with type parameters [misc]"

Tags: python, mypy

When using type aliases with structural pattern matching, `mypy` complains with:

> Class pattern class must not be a type alias with type parameters [misc]

In this case, I have defined an alias `FamilyBrick` for `list[Brick]`, since that's more descriptive.

However, inside `is_family_brick` I'm forced to use `list()`, possible with a type guard to check that each element is a `Brick`. Why can't I use `list[Brick]` as-is?

```
FamilyBrick = list[Brick]
DigitalEntityContent = Brick | FamilyBrick | StickerSheet

class DigitalEntity(FrozenBaseModel):
    content: DigitalEntityContent

    def is_family_brick(self) -> bool:
        match self.content:
            case FamilyBrick():
                return True
            case _:
                return False
```